# Setup HTTP expires headers using PHP and Apache

Tags: php, performance, apache, http

How can I setup expires headers in PHP + Apache? I'm currently using an auto_prepend to serve resources gzipped but I'd also like to maximise the HTTP cache.

How can I set these up?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  The first is to specify the header in your php code.  This is great if you want to programatically adjust the expiry time.  For example a wiki could set a longer expires time for a page which is not edited very often.

```
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + (60 * 60))); // 1 hour
```

Your second choice is to create an **.htaccess** file or modify your httpd config.  In a shared hosting environment, modifying your .htaccess file is quite common.  In order to do this, you need to know if your server supports **mod_expires**, **mod_headers** or both.  The easiest way is simply trial and error, but some Apache servers are configured to let you view this information via the /server-info page.  If your server has both mod_expires and mod_headers, and you want to set the expiry on static resources, try putting this in your .htaccess file:

```
# Turn on Expires and set default to 0
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# Set up caching on media files for 1 year (forever?)
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
ExpiresDefault A29030400
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
```

For other combinations and more examples see: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-your-site-with-caching-and-cache-control.html

Comment: So I'm right in thinking that .flv, .ico etc will automatically have the correct headers prepended to them? very cool

Comment: Header append Cache-Control "public" => This line gives me a 500 internal server error.

Comment: @noobcode I have the exact same problem. How did you solve this please?

Comment: To use `Header` you need mod_headers. Eg run `a2enmod` and type `headers` then restart Apache.

Comment: Great answer. But never do more than 1 year because this violates the RFC guidelines.

Comment: Note that you can just use `gmdate('r')` which provides a valid RFC 2822 representation.

Answer (score 2):

This Apache module might be of help:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html

Comment: I would also look into using mod_expires before going with a PHP alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like?

```
<?php
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
?>
```