# how to set expiry date or a maximum age http headers

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, server

how to set expire date for static resources in http headers

Leverage browser caching
Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.
Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js (expiration not specified)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup HTTP expires headers using PHP and Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036941/setup-http-expires-headers-using-php-and-apache)

Answer (score 0):

Load and configure mod_expires: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html